# Unique random - srand in java ? (like in c++)

Tags: java, android-studio, random, srand

Currently I'm using a

```
Random rand = new Random();
myNumber = rand.nextInt((100-0)+1)+0;
```

and it's a pseudo-random, because I always get the same sequence of numbers.
I remember in c++ you could just use the ctime and use srand to make it unique. How do you do it in java ?

Comment: Use [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html)

Comment: The C++ version is not completely unique by the way. It's just that you can explicitly seed the generator (as you can in Java too).

Comment: The only way to always get the same sequence of numbers is to reuse the same seed. Remove the seed you're using and you'll be getting random numbers again.

Comment: It does that because `Random` is using a seed generated during the _compilation_ process. Once your program is built, the sequence will be the same. As @Ferrybig said, try using `SecureRandom` ([SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html)) or try to implement `Random(seed)` as your _seed_ is randomly generated during the _runtime_. By the way, the question is interresting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If you require a unique random in Java, use [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html). This class provides a cryptographically strong random number generator (RNG), meaning it can be used when creating certificates and this class is slow compared to the other solutions.
- If you require a predictable random that you can reset, use a [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), where you call `.setSeed(number)` to seed it to make the values predictable from that point.
- If you want a pseudo-random that is random every time you start the program, use a normal [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). A random instance is seed by default by some hash of the current time.

For the best randomness in every solution, it is important to RE-USE the random instance. If this isn't done, most of the output it gives will be similar over the same timespan, and at the case of a thrown away SecureRandom, it will spend a lot of time recreating the new random.